# Alternative way to use ternary without an else

Tags: javascript

Is there a cleaner way to achive this?

```
const message = `Error message: ${json.email ? json.email[0] : ''}`
```

Comment: You can do `(json.email || [''])[0]`.

Comment: @Alex, sorry I asked it wrongly, but I was specifically asking about the usage of JavaScript logical operators, not necessarily a better way to achieve.

Comment: @Alex edited the question.

Comment: @AliAnkarali no worries, it's totally ok to asking it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` as below

```
(arr || [''])[0]
```

If `arr` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) then a new array with empty string as first element is used. `[0]` will return the first element of array.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use it like that. Will mark as accepted after the timer ends.

Comment: Just a side question bothering me.. isnt the idea of this wrong? I mean if arr is defined yet has no content, it is still going to return undefined, kind of ignoring the purpose of the empty string.

Comment: @Lain True. But that's what OP is doing. I have provided an alternative to OP's code.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Just a question also maybe for the OP to rethink his idea. Not saying that your answer is wrong :-)

Comment: @Ali Ankarali: Well what I wonder is, if you really want to return undefined if the array has no content (var arr = []; console.log(1, (arr || [''])[0])) and only an empty string if the array itself is undefined (var arr = undefined; console.log(1, (arr || [''])[0])). I would like to have either undefined or an empty string in both cases.

Comment: Ah, in my case, if there is an array, it is never empty. However let's say it can be, then I would like to return an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is tc39 proposal on that: [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). 
After it is live it would be as easy as

```
const message = `Error message: ${json?.email?.[0] || ''} ${json?.password?.[0] || ''} ${json?.username?.[0] || ''}`
```

"Stage 1" means "it seems to be on the way to be discussed".
You can use such a syntax that with help of Babel.

Otherwise(no Babel) you better use helper like [lodash's _.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) or write your own version. Why don't use ternary operator? Because of its bad readability.

Comment: Wow, that looks cool, thanks. I use some stage 1 features so I may add this one.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ternary operation, always return a value. Logical operators should be use with careful.

> As logical expressions are evaluated from left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:

- false && (anything) is evaluated as false by short circuit.
- true ||(anything) is evaluated as true through short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use lodash, you can use the [_.get method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get), which lets you specify a whole path of nested property accessors and if any property along the path is not found it can optionally return a default value:

```
_.get(json, 'password[0]', '');
```

So your example would translate to something like this:

```
const message = `Error message: ${_.get(json, 'email[0]', '')} ${_.get(json, 'password[0]', '')} ${_.get(json, 'username[0]', '')}`
```